# Is $G$ a secure PRG?

Tags: algorithm-design, provable-security, pseudo-random-generator

Is the following function a secure PRG?

> Given $F$ is a secure PRG and $k$ is choosen random from key space $K$.
>
> $$G(x) = F(k,x) \oplus F(k,x \oplus 1^s)$$

My solution is $x \oplus 1^s = x'$ so $G(x)$ becomes $f \oplus f'$ with $f = F(k,x)$ and $f' = F(k,x')$. Clearly $f$ and $f'$ are PRG, i.e. generate random strings; and $\oplus$ of these will be random.

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: G(x xor 1^s) = F(k,x xor 1^s) xor F(k,x xor 1^s xor 1^s) = F(k,x xor 1^s) xor F(k,x xor 0^s) = F(k,x xor 1^s) xor F(k,x) = F(k,x) xor F(k,x xor 1^s) = G(x)

Comment: You should specify what F is (I assume a pseudorandom function) and where k comes from.

Comment: Ricky is right, but he forgot to say what it meant: G is not a secure PRG. And yeah, using $F$ without specification is bad. And toughts like this are not always as clear. Your only hint was "clearly $f$ and $f'$ are PRG".

Comment: @RickyDemer, care to write it up as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

To give this question its deserved answer, I’ll repeat [what Ricky Demer noted](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/16031/is-g-is-a-secure-prg?rq=1#comment34007_16031) in his comment:

$$G(x \oplus 1^s) = F(k,x \oplus 1^s) \oplus F(k,x \oplus 1^s \oplus 1^s)  \\
\downarrow  \\
F(k,x \oplus 1^s) \oplus F(k,x \oplus 1^s \oplus 1^s) = F(k,x \oplus 1^s) \oplus F(k,x \oplus 0^s)  \\
\downarrow  \\
F(k,x \oplus 1^s) \oplus F(k,x \oplus 0^s) = F(k,x \oplus 1^s) \oplus F(k,x)  \\
\downarrow  \\
F(k,x \oplus 1^s) \oplus F(k,x) = F(k,x) \oplus F(k,x \oplus 1^s)  \\
\downarrow  \\
F(k,x) \oplus F(k,x \oplus 1^s) = G(x)$$

As [tylo commented](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/16031/is-g-is-a-secure-prg/27234?noredirect=1#comment34027_16031): This shows G is not a secure PRG.

Answer (score 1):

If, as can be reasonably inferred from the question, a fresh random $k$ is chosen on each invocation of $G$, then $G$ is not a pseudorandom generator because it is not deterministic. (A pseudorandom generator by definition is a deterministic algorithm.)

If $k$ is fixed, then more information would be needed. For example, is $k$ always the same, or is a different $k$ used depending on the length of $x$ (*i.e.*, is $G$ actually a *family* of algorithms)?